# How to get loaded image property in phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I have a problem for getting properties of loaded image in Phaser.js.

Now I resolve it by accessing private variable (a suck method I known...):

```
var image = game.textures.get("imageA") 
console.log("width",image.frames.__BASE.width);
```

Does anyone has a better solution to get these properties?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your UseCase, you could use the `getSourceImage` or `get` method, of the `Texture` object.

It is abit longer, also but works *(if you need/want the html element )*:

```
  var image = game.textures.get("imageA");
  console.info(image.getSourceImage().width);
```

here the [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.Texture.html#getSourceImage__anchor)

Or you could use the `get` function of the texture *(if you need/want the phaser frame)*:

```
  var image = game.textures.get("imageA");
  console.info(image.get().width);
```

here the [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.Texture.html#get__anchor)

The parameter for `get` and `getSourceImage` are optional, but you could enter a name/index of a frame, if you need a specific frame.